# Google Spreadsheets API Column Titles

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-data-api

I am using the Google Spreadsheets API in python, and I can't get the column headers for the ListView of a worksheet.

Does anyone know how to get those titles? I can only find the underscore preceded hashes.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a this [library](https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-amazon-simple-product-api) I created, its a simple wrapper to the spreadsheet API designed to make cases like the one you are facing much simpler to deal with.

Comment: I have been using this, but when I call get_rows() on a worksheet I get a list of dicts that have random hashes for keys instead of the column headers in the worksheet.

Comment: Hi @mvid, I just tested this and it seems to work fine. Are you sure that in your worksheet columns have proper headers? If they do please open a bug on [github](https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-google-spreadsheet/issues) and give me access to a worksheet with which i can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately my headers are not hardcoded, rather they reference other strings. I don't believe it is a bug, simply something wrong with my use case.